# Summation to Integration in Statistical Mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In Statistical Mechanics, what is the procedure of replacing this summation by the integration given by $$\sum_{\vec k} \rightarrow \frac{V}{(2\pi)^3} \int_{0}^{\infty} 4\pi k^2 dk$$

Comment: If $|\Delta \vec{k}| \ll |\vec{k}|$ holds for most of the states in the heat bath then we can approximate $\Delta \vec{k} \sim d\vec{k}$ and send the sum to an integral. There is no real procedure involved, you just replace the sum by an integral and send the summand to an integrand.

Comment: I guess, there should be a method to it.

Comment: @FenderLesPaul: I think maybe OP wants to understand where the $V$ comes from, etc. This is not completely trivial. Try explaining about the mode density in a box of volume $V$.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143467/2451

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is already contained inside [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/147184/23596). Without reiterating the same answer again, essentially there is a conversion from Cartesian to spherical coordinates:

\begin{align}
\int\int\int\rho(k)dk_xdk_ydk_z &=  \int^k_0\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{\pi}_{0}\rho(k)k^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi dk\\
&= \frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\int^k_04\pi k^2dk
\end{align}

where $k$ is the "radius" of the spherical coordinate system.